# SATA Card Blocks On-Board RAID Controller

Tags: raid, sata, pci-express

I have a PCI-Express two-port SATA card (from SSU).
It is model SU-SATA3-T2.
I'm installing it in a Dell Optiplex 990.  The Dell motherboard part number is 06D7TR.

The card seems to work, but with one big problem: it disables the four motherboard SATA ports.

The mother board has four SATA ports that are taken up by four hard drives that are in two RAID1 arrays. I'd like to connect the DVD drive, and that's why I bought the two-port card. Unfortunately, the card seems to want to be the only SATA interface.

Simply installing the card doesn't cause a problem. On boot-up, first I see the card's BIOS. Since I haven't connected any devices to it, it correctly reports, "Can't find any devices." I suspect that it then kills itself, making way for the internal RAID controller BIOS. I then see the usual display of RAID virtual drives and their respective component physical drives.

If I connect my DVD drive to the SATA card then, on boot-up, I see the report from the SATA card BIOS, but *nothing* from the internal RAID controller. Then, I get "No boot device found".

On checking the system BIOS, I see that the system sees the individual hardware drives, but *not* the RAID virtual drives; hence, no boot device.

I checked for address collisions, I/O, and IRQ conflicts: nothing.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Some motherboards disable sets of SATA ports depending on whether something is inserted (or potentially active) in one of the PCIe slots. Essentially there are a set of lanes from the motherboard chipset that are switched between the slot and the SATA controller. You should check your motherboard manual.

Comment: Is this behavior something that can be controlled in the CMOS settings?

Comment: Sometimes, and only insofar as you can choose which one might work. Most often though it is "you have something working in this slot so the SATA is disabled."

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that only the RAID is disabled.  In the CMOS configurator, the drives in the on-board SATA ports are still detected individually.  Only the virtual (RAID) volumes are missing.

Comment: I would plug it into a different PCIe slot first.  Maybe try several different slots.